# Reverse Proxy - SSL Certificate for an infinite number of domain

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt

Currently I have a NGINX Reverse proxy (**server A**) setup that redirect all request to another server (**server B**).

I have an infinite number of domain name that have DNS A Record pointing to **server A**. Basically the **Server A** is a server with a static ip. So customer using my app can set up their domain name to point to **server A** and then the server redirect to **server B** is dynamic ip so that's why I have the **server A**.

Now what I want to achieve is that all domain pointing to **server A** should use HTTPS.

As my reverse proxy is not setup to accept ssl certificate, the request are blocked. I got this error while attempting to access from a domain `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

The issue is, as I can have an infinite number of domain what is the best solution to make sure that all the domain can use HTTPS.

Is there a way in NGINX + Let's Encrypt to do something that would accept all domain?

Otherwise should I update and create a SSL certificate manually for each new domain and update the NGINX config?

Thank you! :)

EDIT: While manually creating the certificate on the **server A** it's working but I would need to figure out a way to automatically create the file ... Or find another solution.

Comment: If the domains are not subdomains of one domain then you have to configure them individually (one certificate can be for multiple domains but you have to specify each domain). For subdomains you could use a wild-card certificate.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, I will have a look at this!